# how to setup github workflow push without failing on no changes?

Tags: github, github-actions, git-push

I want to automate a process.
It should write all the files which are contained in a folder to a file.
I managed to do this with:

`ls ./path/to/mydir > ./path/to/myfile.txt`

in my github-actions workflow it looks like this:

```yaml
name: push
on: [push]
jobs:
  list-contents:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: ls ./src/content/ > ./src/_content.txt
      - run: |
          git config --local user.email "antboehler@gmail.com"
          git config --local user.name "AntVil"
          git add ./src/_content.txt
          git commit -m "update _content.txt"
      - uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          force: true
```

This works. The problem I'm facing is, my workflow fails, when there is no change in the file to be commited. It would be nice if I could stop the workflow before the error occurs, so that the workflow doesn't show the error.

I would do it like this:

- check if there are changes with `git diff --exit-code ./src/_content.txt`
- stop the action before doing any of the git commands

or

- skip all further actions

The main problem is I don't know how to implement that I code, because I'm new to github-actions.
I'm just completly stuck.

**EDIT:**

think I got it finally working, if there is a better way, please let me know

```yaml
name: push
on: [push]
jobs:
  list-contents:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: ls ./src/content/ > ./src/_content.txt
      - run: if [[ "$(git diff --exit-code src/_content.txt)" =~ 'diff' ]]; then echo "IS_VALID=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV; else echo "IS_VALID=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV ;fi
      - if: ${{ env.IS_VALID == 'true' }}
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "antboehler@gmail.com"
          git config --local user.name "AntVil"
          git add ./src/_content.txt
          git commit -m "update _content.txt"
      - if: ${{ env.IS_VALID == 'true' }}
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          force: true
```